# Reverse Engineering Movable Labels in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.5, annotation

I have an .mxd where the labels for most features are fully editable and movable. However, they have NOT been converted to notation. They are stored in shapefiles that have no symbology but also have "Label Features" checked off. When a shapefile is checked off, the labels turn off as well. We can't figure out how this is possible but we'd like to be able to recreate this label style since it works really well.

How can I recreate this?

I am not new to GIS, please trust that I understand what a shapefile is.

I am using ArcMap 10.5.1.

Comment: How does the attribute table look like, could you post an extract ?

Comment: Also are you really using a shapefile ? (a file with an .shp extension an the accompanying .dbf .shx and .prj)

Comment: It is a shapefile. If I export the shapefile to a copy and add it to the map, it shows up with the regular symbology. The attribute table is also typical of a shapefile: FID, Shape, etc

Comment: Is it possible that it is actually annotation stored in the .mxd, rather than a .gdb?

Comment: Nope, it's definitely not the annotation! The option to convert labels to annotation is still there and still functional, and I can still edit the labels within the attribute table.

Comment: Are you sure? You can convert more labels to anno with annotation stored in the .mxd. No annotation groups in the data frame properties?

Comment: I think you're right! It seems like they're annotations stored within the .mxd. I recreated labels with the same functionality by doing it that way and they seem the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your labels are not actually labels, they are annotation. You are dealing with annotation created in the map document, rather than in a geodatabase. Open the data frame properties to view all of the .mxd's annotation groups.

Comment: I had no idea you could view all the annotation groups that way, thank you!